# jquery add span element only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the form put into table (i have shown only first line. All other are the same):

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="login">Username</label></td>
    <td>
       <input id="login" type="text" path="login" placeholder="Enter Login"
                                       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please fill this field - it is mandatory')"
                                       oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is add before "input" element" span" element, but only once, meaning before add it - check if one exists. In other words in the result it should be like this:

```
<span></span><input ...
```

And code smth like this:

```
var spanvar = "<span/>";
 if($('input').prev("span").length==0) --> check if there is no <span> before
 {
    $("input".before(spanvar)); ---> add span element but only once
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
// Iterate through every input
$("input").each(function(){

  // If no span
  if($(this).prev("span").length==0){

    // Add span before this
    $(spanvar).insertBefore(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: But does prev work if previous element is not input but span?

Comment: @ovod i didn't get you? Please explain

Comment: From docs: prev() - Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. But <span> is not sibling. It still givw me span element?

Answer (score 0):

check if element before current is of type `span`

```
$(this).prev().is('span')
```

so you could proov

```
var $prev = $(this).prev();

if($prev.length == 0 || !$prev.is('span') {
    $(this).before( $('<span>') );
}
```